# How to swap columns in a tsv file, while keeping the tab delimiter?

Tags: awk, text-formatting

For example, you have:

> name  1   2   3   4   5   6   **7 8**

With tab delimiter ^

And I want to switch between 2 columns (for example 7th and 8th if you start with 0) so it would look like:

> name  1   2   3   4   5   6   **8 7**

Eventually, it should be probably other column indexes..

I tried using awk but got a lot of errors.
Could you explain?

The command I tried was:

```
awk ' { t = $10; $10 = $9; $9 = t; print > "test2.txt"; } ' test.txt
```

It created a new file, but without the tab delimiter. (With space delimiter)

Comment: Welcome to U/L. Could you please write the awk command you tried?

Comment: Sure,
awk  ' { t = $10; $10 = $9; $9 = t; print > "test2.txt"; } ' test.txt

It created a new file, but without the tab delimiter. (With space delimiter)

Comment: Please add information to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer is the same. Also, you have got the column numbers wrong in your command. Subtract one from each number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to awk this, so here is simple bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do
  cut -f1,2,3 -z <<<"$i"
  printf '\t'
  cut -f10 -z <<<"$i"
  printf '\t'
  cut -f5,6,7,8,9 -z <<<"$i"
  printf '\t'
  cut -f4 <<<"$i"
done <colinput.txt
```

"-z" cut option to not print newline. Its not possible to have option `-f1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7` as cut not change column position in output. cut default delimiter  is tab.

Comment: Thanks, so for example if I want to switch 4th column and 10th column, what should I edit in the command?

Comment: I have update answer to that. First output 1,2,3, then 10, then 5,6,7,8,9, then 4

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. Will try shortly

Comment: Columns not zero based, starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the delimiters. In awk, the *input field separator* is the FS variable, and correspondingly the *output field separator* is OFS. Here are some of the ways to specify these variables:

1. assign the variables in the BEGIN block:

   ```
   awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"} { t = $10; $10 = $9; $9 = t; print } ' test.txt > test2.txt
   ```
2. set the variables within the file list after the awk body

   ```
   awk '{ t = $10; $10 = $9; $9 = t; print } ' FS='\t' OFS='\t' test.txt > test2.txt
   ```
3. using the -F and -v options

   ```
   awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ t = $10; $10 = $9; $9 = t; print } ' test.txt > test2.txt
   ```

---

Additionally, to specify the column numbers you can use these same techniques. I prefer to use -v because it's the cleanest way to pass a *shell* variable into an *awk* variable.

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' -v a=9 -v b=10 '{
    t  = $a
    $a = $b
    $b = t
    print 
}' test.txt > test2.txt
```

Comment: The last awk script seems very simple to understand, but it does something else.
Every 9th column, it copies the first columns instead of just switching

Comment: Eventually, I did manage to run it with a=10 and b=9, thanks a lot!!
The script is easy to understand